# Set Text Property of TextBox and Label in Gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblpsaia" Visible='<%# !(bool) IsInEditMode %>' 
                   runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("psaia") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpsaia" ControlStyle-CssClass="wide" 
                     Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>'
                     runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("psaia") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Can i set Text property of label and textbox dynamically(in C#) in this example?

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically"? During Data_RowBound? Or from client side?

Comment: During Data_RowBound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     Label lblpsaia = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblpsaia");
     lblpsaia.Text = "Sample Text Here";

     TextBox txtpsaia = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtpsaia");
     txtpsaia.Text = "Sample Text Here";
   }
}
```